# Store Arrays of Integers in a Relational Database

Tags: sql-server, database, data-structures, database-design, relational-database

I am writing an app that allows users to track gym exercises.

The data structure is as follows:

An `exercise` has an array of `set`, where each `set` has a value for `reps` and `weight`.

I can display this in JSON in two ways:

Example 1:

```
{
    "id": "primary_key",
    "name": "bench press",
    "sets": [
        {
            "reps": 8,
            "weight": 60
        },
        {
            "reps": 7,
            "weight": 50
        },
        {
            "reps": 6,
            "weight": 40
        }
    ]
}
```

Alternatively, I can flatten the `set` array into two arrays, one for `reps` and one for `weights`, where `reps[0]` pairs with `weights[0]` and so on.

Example 2:

```
{
    "id": "primary_key",
    "name": "bench press",
    "reps": [8, 7, 6],
    "weights": [60, 50, 40]
}
```

Although Example 1 represents a more familiar model of an exercise performed in a workout (it has sets that each have a number of reps and a weight), Example 2 feels compact and efficient (although I would have to check that both the `reps` and `weights` arrays are of equal length before writing the data).

However, I cannot figure out how to represent this data using tables in a relational database such as SQL Server.

I do not want to serialize the reps and weights arrays into a JSON string, as I need to query the values within the arrays.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as far as structuring my data?

Comment: Time to read a published academic textbook on information modeling & database design.  (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not textbooks on doing information modeling & relational database design.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of different options, depending on your 1-many relationships.  Here are a couple possibilities:

Create a single table, with columns:

```
 Exercise     SetNumber    Reps    Weight
 ----------------------------------------
 Bench Press  1            8       60
 Bench Press  2            7       50
```

This has the advantage of simply relating the data you've displayed above.

Alternatively:

Create a table for exercises:

```
Exercise_ID    Exercise_Name
----------------------------
1              Bench Press
```

And another table for sets:

```
 Exercise_ID     SetNumber    Reps    Weight
 ----------------------------------------
 1               1            8       60
 1               2            7       50
```

This is a little more flexible, for instance if you might need to rename your exercises in the future, or if you want to track multiple instances of exercise, each with their own associated sets.

Comment: Thanks! I've decided to use the second option, creating a table for exercises and another table for sets that implements a foreign key on the exercise table.

Answer (score 1):

There is no set structure in SQL Server so you need to use 1..n relationship.

```
Table1
======
ID (pk)
Name

Table2
======
ID (pk identity)
Table1Ref
Reps
Weights
```

Table2 has a foreignkey to Table1 (Tablr1Ref)

This design also allows you simply add/remove (Reps and Weights)

The other solution is using XML column and using XPath query.